# Json encoding with accented characters

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli, encoding

i'm trying to get data from MySql Database.
This is my code.

```
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Quotes WHERE Id=2";

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

$return_arr = array();
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $row_array['Id'] = $row['Id'];
        $row_array['Quote']= $row['Quote'];
        $row_array['Author'] = $row['Author'];
        $row_array['Category'] = $row['Category'];
        $row_array['Likes'] = $row['Likes'];
        array_push($return_arr, $row_array);
    }
}
echo json_encode($return_arr, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

mysqli_close($conn);
```

On the web page nothing appears to me, I found the problem is due to the accented characters like "è or "ò". In fact when i try this:

```
<?php
echo "Result 1";
$return_arr = array();
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $row_array['Id'] = $row['Id'];
        $row_array['Quote']= $row['Quote'];
        $row_array['Author'] = $row['Author'];
        $row_array['Category'] = $row['Category'];
        $row_array['Likes'] = $row['Likes'];
        array_push($return_arr, $row_array);
    }
}
echo json_encode($return_arr, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

echo " Result 2 ";
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM Quotes WHERE Id=2";

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

$return_arr2 = array();
if ($result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
        $row_array['Id'] = $row['Id'];
        $row_array['Quote']= $row['Quote'];
        $row_array['Author'] = $row['Author'];
        $row_array['Category'] = $row['Category'];
        $row_array['Likes'] = $row['Likes'];
        array_push($return_arr2, $row_array);
    }
}

echo json_encode($return_arr2, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I get this result on the screen:
Result 1[ { "Id": "1", "Quote": "My Simple Text", "Author": "Me", "Category": "X", "Likes": "0" } ] Result 2

I'm using php 7.2 and the latest version or MySql.
This is how I configured my database
[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YF0Ft.png)
[Database simple Data for testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pxiqq.png)

UPDATE: I changed all the encodings in utf8_bin but it had no effect. [Database encoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BozO.png) [Columns encoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeJR4.png)
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: use utf8 everywhere

Comment: See mysql set names, Page encoding etc..

Comment: I changed all the encodings in utf8_bin but it seems to have no effect.

Comment: Do You use `mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');` ? https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Answer (score 0):

Try saving all your files in UTF-8 NO BOM format. For example with the notepad as on the following screenshot:

[image]

Does this solve ? I already had this problem ... Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.
I modified my code in this way, thus obtaining the desired result, I hope it will be useful for those with the same problem, the whole database has been encoded in utf8_bin.

```
$return_arr2 = array();
if ($result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
        $row_array['Id'] = $row['Id'];
        $row_array['Quote']= utf8_encode($row['Quote']);
        $row_array['Author'] = $row['Author'];
        $row_array['Category'] = $row['Category'];
        $row_array['Likes'] = $row['Likes'];
        array_push($return_arr2, $row_array);
    }
}

echo json_encode($return_arr2, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

I force the utf8 encoding with "utf8_encode".
Now the result is:

Result 1[ { "Id": "1", "Quote": "My Simple Text", "Author": "Me", "Category": "X", "Likes": "0" } ] Result 2 [ { "Id": "2", "Quote": "My Simplè Text with è or à", "Author": "Me", "Category": "X", "Likes": "0" }

I think that i can use only JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE but i prefer to keep also the others.

Comment: It looks Your connection with database is in CP-1252.